# jquery's fadeIn() similar functionality in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, animation

I wish fadeIn() fadeOut() in Silverlight was as easy as jquery made it!

I have a grid with 2 controls in it..one chart and another a textblock.
At a time only one of them is visible.

I wish to have a smooth transition on both of these controls whenever their visibility changes.

Whats the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a fade in fade out example on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189019%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

SL animations may not be as easy as jquery but they are much richer.

Answer (score 0):

For my game, I just set the opacity to increment on a short timer :)
(www.aaronahearne.co.uk) if you would like to see an example using CompositionTarget.Rendering

Maybe thats not the ideal solution, but thats how we were taught at university to animate in Silverlight

Comment: It is sad to see Universities teaching such a low-level *old-school* practice when Silverlight supports such a rich model specifically for authoring animation using Xaml or even a coded storyboard :(

Comment: Well, its no good teaching people to use simple APIs if they dont know how it all works. Anyone can use .fade().

Comment: Teaching principals of what's *under the hood* is not the same as telling them to ignore the car on the outside and rebuild the wheel each time. University should be about learning how to learn :)

Comment: It is about learning how to learn. I dont see how your argument is in favour of that. Ive done pretty well out of how they've taught me. Who said anything about ignoring the car on the outside? Are you just making this up as you go along?

Comment: Also, discworld is AWESOME btw, but I still dont think youre right about the university stuff!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to use Blend. Open your user control and add two states to the control using the states tab. Name your two states and then setup each state to have the desired visibility and then set the default transition. You can turn on transition preview and switch between the states to see what it looks like.

To have your UI switch between the states add a DataStateBehavior or use a GotToStateAction to swtich them.

Comment: Dont have blend access to blend.